# javascript window redirect doesn't work in chrome ((canceled) - status )

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, redirect

I'm trying to do a redirect using the below code:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
window.location.href = "http://google.com"
</script>
```

FF and IE work as they should. Chrome doesn't.

The request above to http://google.com, gets a 'canceled' status in Chrome browser > Development tools >  "Network".

I've tried several other functions:

```
location.href = url
location.replace(url)
document.location = url
location.assign(url)
window.open(url, '_self')
```

Same code pasted within a local html file works fine.

Below is the redirect request that it's canceled by chrome: http://pastebin.com/hD36M1RG

Any clues? 
Thanks

Comment: That should definitely work. You must have something else causing the problem. Try and reproduce it on http://jsfiddle.net, and please give us what OS and browser version you have.

Comment: Yeah, it should, but it doesn't. 
OS: windows 7
Browser: Google Chrome latest version: 16.0.912.63m

Comment: Something else must be wrong with your code. Can you reproduce the problem on http://jsfiddle.net or alone in a new HTML file?

Comment: Weird. So I copied the redirect code within a local html page, and redirect worked as it should. 
What I don't understand, why the redirect it's just canceled, when it runs from the remote apache server.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know either. At least now you have a better idea of where the problem stems from (Apache).

Comment: <script  type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location.href = "http://google.com"
//-->
</script>

exactly that, it's the response sent from the php file on the server.
same code within a local file, works. but when server by the server, the request to google.com it's canceled within the browser.

Comment: Try to add "http://" in front of the URL and to remove the HTML comments from the script.

Comment: Yeah, did it. Didn't help. Here the details for the redirect request that it's canceled by chrome: http://pastebin.com/hD36M1RG

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm fresh out of ideas. Add those details to your question, maybe someone else will know.

Comment: Google may be refusing a page with a referrer URL that is an non-routable IP address (10.x.x.x).  Try accessing your web page by the server name (e.g. http://localhost/redirect.php if that's what it is) and see if that fixes it.

Comment: This may sound mad but remove the comments - the <!-- and //--> and see if that works?

Comment: Nope, doesn't work using localhost either. I may add there any redirect URL, still canceled , and I've already removed the comments. That didn't work either. 
Many thanks. Still digging.

Comment: @Chris i've the exact same probem with the same Chrome version. This could be a Chrome bug. Works in rest of the browsers IE, firefox, safari.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting a similar problem, the issue was a button submitting a form while executing the `window.location.href = ...` code.

I had to put `type="button"` in the button attributes to prevent it from submitting.

Answer (score 3):

Try without `window.`, it helped in my case. I had used `location.assign()` instead of `window.location.assign()` and worked.

Comment: Verified this to work, any idea if using both window.location and location break anything? I'm using both, seems to work real well.

Answer (score 3):

I was doing the same thing. A quick patch was to add a little delay before the redirect using **setTimeout**.

Comment: I also worked around this behavior, but it feels like a hack that will break at some point.

Answer (score 2):

I had a somewhat similar issue, (but it did not work on Firefox either). The problem was just that i forgot to add `http://` in :

```
window.location.href = `http://${ window.location.host }/pages/${ name }/`
```

Answer (score 0):

using **setTimeout** worked for me, and i'm facing this problem with vue-router, tring to redirect to an auth page in 'beforeEach' hook.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a problem about vue here . Use vue.nextTick (function () ()) solved it.

```
Vue.nextTick(function () {
   window.location.href="/***/****_view.action
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Chrome wants to first complete some (or all) of the outstanding AJAX calls before redirecting or reloading the page, so it is worthwhile examining your traffic.

For me, it happened because multiple AJAX requests were being sent at the same time from within a `setInterval` function executing at a high rate.
I had to `clearInterval` in order to get the `window.location.href` request to not get cancelled.

That would explain why `setTimeout` worked for some people above.