# Disable back button while payment transaction occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml, spring-security

I have an XHTML page which is called after a successful credit card payment. But when the user hits the back button, he's charged again. How can I handle the issue, by either disabling the back button or invalidating his session when he hits back space or back button.

I am using Spring3/JSF but this problem has no relevance to this reference as this is a browser issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644150/javascript-redirection-issue-with-google-chrome). Faced the same issue myself.

Comment: It's not a browser issue, it's an issue on you server side code!

Comment: on the successful credit card payment load , on the server side juste destroy the sesson information.

Comment: A cheap solution some sites use is to perform the transaction in a new window/dialog/iframe, and then remove that new window/dialog/iframe on completion of the transaction so there's no page history to go back to.

Comment: @Abhi  did u find any solution, i'm having same problem.

Answer (score 6):

Thats the wrong design. Don't try to manipulate the client from doing bad things - prevent the client from being able to do bad things.

Case in point, use a unique token for each transaction so that if the user clicks back and resubmits the transaction it will be rejected and the user can be notified that the transaction has already gone through.

Comment: I think its not a wrong design , we have to provide a return URL to the payment gateway and after posting to the gateway it redirects to that url