# Prevent user to going to payment gateway by clicking browser back

Tags: c#, reactjs, browser, payment-gateway

I'm working on website where payment is being processed. I want to prevent user to go to payment gateway by clicking browser back after payment process is completed (successfully/unsuccessfully). I'm using react as the front end.

Please suggest how to implement this

Comment: What research have you done that didn't provide the answer? What differed to your specific case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756848/disable-back-button-while-payment-transaction-occurs)

Answer (score 1):

This is the **incorrect approach**. Breaking the web browser user flow is not only going to cause you pain in the long term (*around incorrect assumptions*), but will also cause user frustration. The reality is that you won't be able to fully disable the back button - in most modern browsers, the user can back out several levels back.

What you can do instead is detect [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) and handle that appropriately and give the user notice that they will lose their work/state.