# Remove browser back button history Angular

Tags: angular, browser

In my application i have a 3rd party **payment** page. Once payment is done it will redirect to order page. After that if user pressed **browser back button** it should not return to payment page again.

```
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
      window.location.assign("https://github.com/");
    });
```

this code is working if I'm coming back **from** any URL within my website. if I'm coming
from another website (**payment page**) this is not working.

Comment: If your order page will always came from payment page only then you can try to stop back button on your order page. using
window.onbeforeunload = function() { return false; };

Hope this help. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8756892/11004482

Comment: Take a look at https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationBehaviorOptions. It may be useful.